# SWIFT tableView rows do not react to selection

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

A bit of context:

I'm filling a tableView with movie titles

[my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1zQc.png)

When one of those rows gets selected I want to go to the movie detail
but when I tap any of the rows nothing happens.

```
class SearchTableViewController: NavigationController{

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var filteredMovies = [Movie]()
    let request = Requests()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    /*
     searches movies from the db which title corresponds to the given text
    */
    func searchMovie(_ keywords: String) {
        request.searchMovie(keywords: keywords){ response in
            for data in response{
                self.filteredMovies.append(data)
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                self.tableView?.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}

extension SearchTableViewController : UITableViewDelegate { }

extension SearchTableViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    /*
     every time a key gets pressed, the table view gets updateted
     with new movie titles
    */
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        self.filteredMovies = [Movie]()
        searchText.isEmpty ? self.tableView?.reloadData() : searchMovie(searchText)
    }
}

extension SearchTableViewController : UITableViewDataSource{

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filteredMovies.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("hello from highlight")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("hello from selection")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didFocusRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("hello from focus")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! SearchTableCell
        cell.onDidSelectMovie = {
            super.goToMovieDetail(movie: self.filteredMovies[indexPath.row])
        }
        let label = cell.contentView.subviews.first as! UILabel
        label.text = filteredMovies[indexPath.row].title
        return cell
    }
}
```

As you can see i tested every function that may show that a row got tapped but none of them works.
I also tried to give to the cells a custom class where I override the behavior of the cell property "isSelected".

```
class SearchTableCell: UITableViewCell {

    var onDidSelectMovie:(()->Void)?

    override var isSelected: Bool{
        didSet {
            if isSelected{
                if let cb = onDidSelectMovie{
                    cb()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another thing that I have want to point out, which may help, is that "selection" on a cell is enabled like "user interactions" but if I try to change selection from "default" to "blue" the color doesn't change.

I literally ran out of ideas and tried many possible solutions but none of them worked. Any suggestion?

Edit: 
I'm going to add everything that can be useful

- the tableView delegate is SearchTableViewController

Comment: Have you assigned SearchTableViewController as a delegate to  tableView?

Comment: Yes it is assigned, gotta update my question

Comment: so... I've removed the delegate and selected again and now it works, I don't know why and I don't want to know it either, thank you a lot in some way you are my savior.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I had just to remove and add again the tableView delegate... don't ask me why, I've spent 2 days on this. Thanks anyway to everyone who tried to help.